# How to find $3 \times 3$ matrix from $2$ given eigenvalues and respective eigenvectors?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> If  $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix with two eigenvalues $2$ and $-1$, and the respective eigenvectors $(1, 2, 0)$ and $(0, 0, 1)$, then what is the vector $A^3 (1, 2, 2)$?

I know the formula for finding the searched matrix is $M=PDP^{−1}$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are the eigenvalues, in the same order as the eigenvectors in $P$. But how to apply this formula for finding $3 \times 3$ matrix given two eigenvalues and the respective eigenvectors?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use MathJax to format your question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It is all given: $v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ with $A v_1 = 2 v_1$ and $v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ with $A v_2 = (-1) v_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Write $$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + 2 \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now, apply $A^n v = \lambda^nv$ for any eigenvector $v$ of eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: How will the value of $ \lambda $ be calculated ?